# How to set dynamic height for dropdown popup in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter development. I am using the dropdown button of my application. When opening the drop-down menu, the text is getting cut in the popup dialog. Below I attached a screenshot with coding. Please guide me in fixing this issue.

```dart
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: new DropdownButton(
        isExpanded: true,
        value: dropDownValue,
        isDense: true,
        //icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down, color: Colors.white,),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
                dropDownValue = newValue;    
                state.didChange(newValue);
            });
        },
        items: dropDownList.map((String value) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem(
                value: value,
                child: new SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
                child: new Text(value,
                    softWrap: true,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),),)
                );
            }).toList(),
        ),
    ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying the `DropdownMenuItem` class as someone else suggested will not be enough as `DropdownButton` requires `items` to be of type `List<DropdownMenuItem<T>>`.

I have created the following widget which should help with your issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Looks like a DropdownButton but has a few differences:
///
/// 1. Can be opened by a single tap even if the keyboard is showing (this might be a bug of the DropdownButton)
///
/// 2. The width of the overlay can be different than the width of the child
///
/// 3. The current selection is highlighted in the overlay
class CustomDropdown<T> extends PopupMenuButton<T> {
  CustomDropdown({
    Key key,
    @required PopupMenuItemBuilder<T> itemBuilder,
    @required T selectedValue,
    PopupMenuItemSelected<T> onSelected,
    PopupMenuCanceled onCanceled,
    String tooltip,
    double elevation = 8.0,
    EdgeInsetsGeometry padding = const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    Icon icon,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    Widget child,
    String placeholder = "Please select",
  }) : super(
    key: key,
    itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
    initialValue: selectedValue,
    onSelected: onSelected,
    onCanceled: onCanceled,
    tooltip: tooltip,
    elevation: elevation,
    padding: padding,
    icon: icon,
    offset: offset,
    child: child == null ? null : Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
            height: 48,
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: selectedValue!= null ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead
                      : Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead.copyWith(color:     
Theme.of(context).hintColor),
                  child: Expanded(child: selectedValue== null ? Text(placeholder) : child),
                ),
                IconTheme(
                  data: IconThemeData(
                    color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                        ? Colors.grey.shade700 : Colors.white70,
                  ),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          bottom: 8,
          child: Container(
            height: 1,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFBDBDBD), width: 0.0)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

It actually extends `PopupMenuButton` as you can see, but I've made it look the same as the `DropdownButton`.

`itemBuilder` needs to return `List<PopupMenuEntry<T>>`, with each entry usually being a `PopupMenuItem` to which you can provide any `child` widget.

`selectedValue` is the currently selected value, which will be highlighted in the overlay. If it is null, a `Text` widget with the `placeholder` string is shown. If it is not null, the `child` widget is shown.

You should be able to disable the highlight by modifying this class to either call `super()` with an `initialValue` of null, or even better add a boolean to the constructor to control this from the outside.

Comment: Is it possible to also post a part of code on how to use "itemBuilder needs to return List<PopupMenuEntry<T>>, with each entry usually being a PopupMenuItem to which you can provide any child widget.". I have tried but get the error error: The argument type 'List<PopupMenuEntry<SearchType>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<PopupMenuEntry<SearchType>> Function(BuildContext)'.

Comment: `itemBuilder` is a function with a `BuildContext` parameter that needs to return `List<PopupMenuEntry>` so it could be used like so: `itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => myList` where `myList` is of type `List<PopupMenuEntry>`

Comment: Thank you, this works like expected. Another interesting article can be found here https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/52a5be814cb4fab3f863517238ca368d

Answer (score 2):

The height of `DropdownMenuItem` is hardcoded to `_kMenuItemHeight`:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L486

The only thing you can do is copy this entire file and adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting the `itemHeight` property of `DropdownButton` to `null`  makes the items have dynamic height.

```
    DropdownButton(
      ... 
      itemHeight: null, 
      ...
    )
```

Documentation link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/itemHeight.html

Comment: This exactly and efficiently solves the original question and should be marked as the correct answer. Not to say that the other solution is wrong, just a little over engineered in contrast.