# Create custom dropdown in flutter - or how to put custom dropdown options in a layer above everything else

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

I am looking for a way to create a custom dropdown so I can style it myself.

I ran into this answer that seems pretty useful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63165793/3808307

The problem is that if the container is smaller than the dropdown, flutter complains about pixel overflowing. How can I get this dropdown to be on top of the other elements in the page, so I don't get this warning? Or is there another way to recreate a custom dropdown without this issue?

All answers I find are regarding the built in DropdownButton

Below, the answer linked above, with editions

---

First, create a dart file named `drop_list_model.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropListModel {
  DropListModel(this.listOptionItems);

  final List<OptionItem> listOptionItems;
}

class OptionItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;

  OptionItem({@required this.id, @required this.title});
}
```

Next, create file `file select_drop_list.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_keeping/model/drop_list_model.dart';
import 'package:time_keeping/widgets/src/core_internal.dart';

class SelectDropList extends StatefulWidget {
  final OptionItem itemSelected;
  final DropListModel dropListModel;
  final Function(OptionItem optionItem) onOptionSelected;

  SelectDropList(this.itemSelected, this.dropListModel, this.onOptionSelected);

  @override
  _SelectDropListState createState() => _SelectDropListState(itemSelected, dropListModel);
}

class _SelectDropListState extends State<SelectDropList> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  OptionItem optionItemSelected;
  final DropListModel dropListModel;

  AnimationController expandController;
  Animation<double> animation;

  bool isShow = false;

  _SelectDropListState(this.optionItemSelected, this.dropListModel);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    expandController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350)
    );
    animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: expandController,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
    _runExpandCheck();
  }

  void _runExpandCheck() {
    if(isShow) {
      expandController.forward();
    } else {
      expandController.reverse();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    expandController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 15, vertical: 17),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2))
              ],
            ),
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.card_travel, color: Color(0xFF307DF1),),
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
              
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      this.isShow = !this.isShow;
                      _runExpandCheck();
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(optionItemSelected.title, style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF307DF1),
                        fontSize: 16),),
                  ),
               
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(1, 0),
                  child: Icon(
                    isShow ? Icons.arrow_drop_down : Icons.arrow_right,
                    color: Color(0xFF307DF1),
                    size: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizeTransition(
              axisAlignment: 1.0,
              sizeFactor: animation,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20), bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 4,
                          color: Colors.black26,
                          offset: Offset(0, 4))
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: _buildDropListOptions(dropListModel.listOptionItems, context)
              )
          ),
//          Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade300, height: 1,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Column _buildDropListOptions(List<OptionItem> items, BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: items.map((item) => _buildSubMenu(item, context)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSubMenu(OptionItem item, BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 26.0, top: 5, bottom: 5),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200], width: 1)),
                ),
                child: Text(item.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF307DF1),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 3,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              ),
            
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () {
          this.optionItemSelected = item;
          isShow = false;
          expandController.reverse();
          widget.onOptionSelected(item);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Initialize value:

```
DropListModel dropListModel = DropListModel([OptionItem(id: "1", title: "Option 1"), OptionItem(id: "2", title: "Option 2")]);
OptionItem optionItemSelected = OptionItem(id: null, title: "Chọn quyền truy cập");
```

Finally use it:

```
Container(height: 47, child: SelectDropList(
           this.optionItemSelected, 
           this.dropListModel, 
           (optionItem){
                 optionItemSelected = optionItem;
                    setState(() {
  
                    });
               },
            ))
```

Comment: Please add what you done yet so far

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I copied the linked answer in the post (it is what I have done, only the dropdown is inside a container which is smaller than the expanded dropdown). Thank you

Comment: Hello, still on

Comment: The answer might depend on the type of customization you want to the apply to the Dropdown, but try using the widget described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354477/how-to-set-dynamic-height-for-dropdown-popup-in-flutter/57443992#57443992

It's basically a PopupMenuButton that works like a Dropdown, which gives you more flexibility around styling. Set your own `itemBuilder` and `child` and if needed adjust the layout built around `child` by `CustomDropdown` to achieve any style you want. The dropdown entries are overlayed on top so you won't have overflow issues.

Comment: Can you share an image for the required UI menu?

Comment: Hi @MohamedReda. I did it copying the code from popup_menu.dart from flutter and editing it into a separate file changing the class names. Thank you

Comment: @user3808307 I see you have added another bounty, this means your question still isn't answered yet. I'd love try to help you. But since I already provided two answers I dnot know what to add without knowing a few more things. What will you archive. What should be difertn to the Material one?

Comment: @M123 I wanted to award to one existing answer, stackoverflow made me wait 12 hours, and I forgot about it. Because even if I did not use your answer, in the sense that I copied the flutter files, it was right that I needed to use the built in components

Comment: Ohh, that is nice from you. Thank you, apriciate it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Custom dropdown below button

I understand that the built-in dropdown works very well but for some use cases, I need something different. For example, if I only have a few items I want the drop-down to appear below the button or have full control of where the dropdown appears. I haven't found a good option yet so I have tried to make my own. I have built on what @M123 mentioned with the overlay and tried to implement it in a similar way to the built-in dropdown. I have found this medium post from the developer of `flutter_typeahead` very useful.
https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9

[image: animated gif of custom dropdown]

The button creates a full-screen stack using overlay. This is so that we can add a full-screen gesture detector behind the dropdown so that it closes when the user taps anywhere on the screen.

The overlay is linked to the button using a `LayerLink` and the `CompositedTransformFollower` widget.

We also use `RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();` to easily get the position and size of the button. Then position the dropdown accoridingly.

#### the Dropdown file

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class CustomDropdown<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  /// the child widget for the button, this will be ignored if text is supplied
  final Widget child;

  /// onChange is called when the selected option is changed.;
  /// It will pass back the value and the index of the option.
  final void Function(T, int) onChange;

  /// list of DropdownItems
  final List<DropdownItem<T>> items;
  final DropdownStyle dropdownStyle;

  /// dropdownButtonStyles passes styles to OutlineButton.styleFrom()
  final DropdownButtonStyle dropdownButtonStyle;

  /// dropdown button icon defaults to caret
  final Icon icon;
  final bool hideIcon;

  /// if true the dropdown icon will as a leading icon, default to false
  final bool leadingIcon;
  CustomDropdown({
    Key key,
    this.hideIcon = false,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.items,
    this.dropdownStyle = const DropdownStyle(),
    this.dropdownButtonStyle = const DropdownButtonStyle(),
    this.icon,
    this.leadingIcon = false,
    this.onChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomDropdownState<T> createState() => _CustomDropdownState<T>();
}

class _CustomDropdownState<T> extends State<CustomDropdown<T>>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  bool _isOpen = false;
  int _currentIndex = -1;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _expandAnimation;
  Animation<double> _rotateAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    _expandAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
    _rotateAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var style = widget.dropdownButtonStyle;
    // link the overlay to the button
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: this._layerLink,
      child: Container(
        width: style.width,
        height: style.height,
        child: OutlinedButton(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            padding: style.padding,
            backgroundColor: style.backgroundColor,
            elevation: style.elevation,
            primary: style.primaryColor,
            shape: style.shape,
          ),
          onPressed: _toggleDropdown,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment:
                style.mainAxisAlignment ?? MainAxisAlignment.center,
            textDirection:
                widget.leadingIcon ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              if (_currentIndex == -1) ...[
                widget.child,
              ] else ...[
                widget.items[_currentIndex],
              ],
              if (!widget.hideIcon)
                RotationTransition(
                  turns: _rotateAnimation,
                  child: widget.icon ?? Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.caretDown),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    // find the size and position of the current widget
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var size = renderBox.size;
    
    var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    var topOffset = offset.dy + size.height + 5;
    return OverlayEntry(
      // full screen GestureDetector to register when a
      // user has clicked away from the dropdown
      builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => _toggleDropdown(close: true),
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        // full screen container to register taps anywhere and close drop down
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                left: offset.dx,
                top: topOffset,
                width: widget.dropdownStyle.width ?? size.width,
                child: CompositedTransformFollower(
                  offset:
                      widget.dropdownStyle.offset ?? Offset(0, size.height + 5),
                  link: this._layerLink,
                  showWhenUnlinked: false,
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: widget.dropdownStyle.elevation ?? 0,
                    borderRadius:
                        widget.dropdownStyle.borderRadius ?? BorderRadius.zero,
                    color: widget.dropdownStyle.color,
                    child: SizeTransition(
                      axisAlignment: 1,
                      sizeFactor: _expandAnimation,
                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: widget.dropdownStyle.constraints ??
                            BoxConstraints(
                              maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                                  topOffset -
                                  15,
                            ),
                        child: ListView(
                          padding:
                              widget.dropdownStyle.padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          children: widget.items.asMap().entries.map((item) {
                            return InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() => _currentIndex = item.key);
                                widget.onChange(item.value.value, item.key);
                                _toggleDropdown();
                              },
                              child: item.value,
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleDropdown({bool close = false}) async {
    if (_isOpen || close) {
      await _animationController.reverse();
      this._overlayEntry.remove();
      setState(() {
        _isOpen = false;
      });
    } else {
      this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
      Overlay.of(context).insert(this._overlayEntry);
      setState(() => _isOpen = true);
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }
}

/// DropdownItem is just a wrapper for each child in the dropdown list.\n
/// It holds the value of the item.
class DropdownItem<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final T value;
  final Widget child;

  const DropdownItem({Key key, this.value, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return child;
  }
}

class DropdownButtonStyle {
  final MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;
  final ShapeBorder shape;
  final double elevation;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final BoxConstraints constraints;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color primaryColor;
  const DropdownButtonStyle({
    this.mainAxisAlignment,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.primaryColor,
    this.constraints,
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.elevation,
    this.padding,
    this.shape,
  });
}

class DropdownStyle {
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;
  final double elevation;
  final Color color;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final BoxConstraints constraints;

  /// position of the top left of the dropdown relative to the top left of the button
  final Offset offset;

  ///button width must be set for this to take effect
  final double width;

  const DropdownStyle({
    this.constraints,
    this.offset,
    this.width,
    this.elevation,
    this.color,
    this.padding,
    this.borderRadius,
  });
}
```

#### using the dropdown

I have tried to make using the custom dropdown similar to the built-in one with the added bonus of being able to style the actual dropdown, as well as the button.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: CustomDropdown<int>(
        child: Text(
          'dropdown',
        ),
        onChange: (int value, int index) => print(value),
        dropdownButtonStyle: DropdownButtonStyle(
          width: 170,
          height: 40,
          elevation: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          primaryColor: Colors.black87,
        ),
        dropdownStyle: DropdownStyle(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          elevation: 6,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        ),
        items: [
          'item 1',
          'item 2',
          'item 3',
          'item 4',
        ]
            .asMap()
            .entries
            .map(
              (item) => DropdownItem<int>(
            value: item.key + 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(item.value),
            ),
          ),
        )
            .toList(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I am sure there will be some improvements needed in there somewhere. But it's working for me at the moment.

Comment: The "CustomDropdown" has plenty of errors with Flutter 2.2.3 Dart 2.13.4, any idea?

Comment: The principal should work still but the above code is not null safe. You will need to migrate the code to null safe. I will look at doing that for the answer soon.

Comment: great solution. null-safety fix is required, but it does not depend on library and is freely custom.

Answer (score 12):

#### Dropdown decision

I would recommend using the standard Flutter drop down menu. Because it is very robust, easy to write and has been tried and tested. You said that you would like to style your drop down yourself, I suspect that this is the reason why you decided against the standard. But this doesn't have to be the case. The standard drop down menu can be designed pretty well. More on that below

#### Example Code

```
  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```

#### Style

Your `DropdownMenuItem` will follow your ThemeData class. Not only its `backgroundColor` will match the canvasColor in your ThemeData class, but also it will follow the same `TextStyle`.

The Theme data has to be initialized in the Material App:

```
return MaterialApp(
    //....
    theme: new ThemeData(
            fontFamily: "Encode Sans", //my custom font
            canvasColor: _turquoise, //my custom color
            //other theme data
            ),
     //.....
),
```

If you don't want to or can't work with theme data, this may be something for you.
The DropdownButton class has an inbuilt variable called `dropdownColor` which can be assigned any color you need directly, without changing any `ThemeData`. Automatically changes the color of the dropdown menu items as well.

For example, if you want to change the With from the dropdown you can feed its child property a new `Container` and add the desired `width`. just make sure you use a suitable width so that you do not get overflow problems later on when you use the menu within a more complex layout. I would still recommend leaving the width on dynamic.

In addition, the `DropDownButton` has the ability to expand, which means that it takes up all the space it can get

```
DropdownButton<String>(
   isExpanded: true,
)
```

Comment: You just finished writing the answer and got an upvote! Even reading your answer will take more than 5 mins.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wrote such a big text. But since I didn't follow your question exactly, I took a little more time to explain why I would suggest the other way

Comment: Hey, I'm not OP, but I just saw after I wrote the comment, somebody took off their upvote.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't notice. I answered several questions today so I can already imagine that something like this happened. About a month ago I received a notification that someone I had helped upvoted many of my answers one after the other. Of course, this reputation was not attributed to me lol.
Again regarding your question, what do you think of my proposal

Comment: Yes, @M123, the problem with the dropdown that comes with flutter is the styling. For example, where to place the dropdown in regards to the button. It has no flexibility in that sense. Regarding overflow, the one that comes with flutter has no overflow problem, it is in a layer above. What I want to achive is have my own dropdown that will behave as the built in with no overflow, but that can be fully customizable in appearance

Comment: So your goal is to move your dropdown further away from the button or what do you want to achieve. I'll see if I can find a way later

Comment: @M123 for example that it makes the selected element be in the middle (after you select, when you reopen, the selected item is in the vertical axis at the same coordinate as the dropdown button), or having a shadow instead of elevation. I ended up copying PopupMenuButton code into a separate file, renaming the classes, and worked from there. I don't know if it was the best option

Comment: @M123 Also it has this padding added by the widget that I did not want. Flutter assumes the styling. Most people, at least that I know of, work with designer, so the styling can't be defined by Flutter, I hate that side of it, it reminds me of WP.

Comment: @user3808307 It's great that you found a solution, I didn't understand that with the padding, have you tried both of my answers, maybe the second one with the OverlayEntry works better for you.

Answer (score 6):

I found a new way to build a custom drop down, by using Overlay.

[Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html):

> Overlays let independent child widgets "float" visual elements on top
> of other widgets by inserting them into the overlay's Stack. The
> overlay lets each of these widgets manage their participation in the
> overlay using OverlayEntry objects.

This gives you all the design freedom, as every kind of child is allowed. How to move the DropDown I wrote as comments in the code.

Here is a small sample, how to use it.

```
OverlayEntry floatingDropdown;


AnyButton(
   //...
   onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (isDropdownOpened) {
            floatingDropdown.remove();
          } else {
            findDropdownData();
            floatingDropdown = _createFloatingDropdown();
            Overlay.of(context).insert(floatingDropdown);
          }

          isDropdownOpened = !isDropdownOpened;
        });
      },
);




  OverlayEntry _createFloatingDropdown() {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        // You can change the position here
        left: xPosition,
        width: width,
        top: yPosition + height,
        height: 4 * height + 40,
        // Any child
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          height: height,
          child: Text('Hallo'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

A full fully designed example can be found [here](https://github.com/TechieBlossom/flutter-samples/blob/master/custom_dropdown.dart).

Comment: The problem with this one is that the dropdown button is in list items. So having to set the position for each individually is not really convenients. Specially when the ones at the bottom need to open up (so as to not go out of bounds of the page), and the ones on the top have to open down.

Answer (score 3):

I have improved the answer provided by Dan James with to match **2023**.

- fixed few issues
- added scrollbar for dropdown
- added shape customization for dropdown

  ~ publishing as a answer because there are many pending edits and not responded.

**Dropdown class**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomDropdown<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  /// the child widget for the button, this will be ignored if text is supplied
  final Widget child;

  /// onChange is called when the selected option is changed.;
  /// It will pass back the value and the index of the option.
  final void Function(int) onChange;

  /// list of DropdownItems
  final List<DropdownItem<T>> items;
  final DropdownStyle dropdownStyle;

  /// dropdownButtonStyles passes styles to OutlineButton.styleFrom()
  final DropdownButtonStyle dropdownButtonStyle;

  /// dropdown button icon defaults to caret
  final Icon? icon;
  final bool hideIcon;

  /// if true the dropdown icon will as a leading icon, default to false
  final bool leadingIcon;

  const CustomDropdown({
    Key? key,
    this.hideIcon = false,
    required this.child,
    required this.items,
    this.dropdownStyle = const DropdownStyle(),
    this.dropdownButtonStyle = const DropdownButtonStyle(),
    this.icon,
    this.leadingIcon = false,
    required this.onChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomDropdown> createState() => _CustomDropdownState();
}

class _CustomDropdownState<T> extends State<CustomDropdown<T>> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0);
  late OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  bool _isOpen = false;
  int _currentIndex = -1;
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _expandAnimation;
  late Animation<double> _rotateAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    _expandAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
    _rotateAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var style = widget.dropdownButtonStyle;
    // link the overlay to the button
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: _layerLink,
      child: Container(
        width: style.width,
        height: style.height,
        padding: style.padding,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: style.backgroundColor,
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: _toggleDropdown,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: style.mainAxisAlignment ?? MainAxisAlignment.center,
            textDirection: widget.leadingIcon ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              // if (_currentIndex == -1) ...[
              widget.child,
              // ]
              // else ...[
              //   widget.items[_currentIndex],
              // ],
              if (!widget.hideIcon)
                RotationTransition(
                  turns: _rotateAnimation,
                  child: widget.icon ??
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 7),
                        child: RotatedBox(
                          quarterTurns: 3,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                            size: 13,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    // find the size and position of the current widget
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    var size = renderBox.size;

    var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    var topOffset = offset.dy + size.height + 5;
    return OverlayEntry(
      // full screen GestureDetector to register when a
      // user has clicked away from the dropdown
      builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => _toggleDropdown(close: true),
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        // full screen container to register taps anywhere and close drop down
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                left: offset.dx,
                top: topOffset,
                width: widget.dropdownStyle.width ?? size.width,
                child: CompositedTransformFollower(
                  offset: widget.dropdownStyle.offset ?? Offset(0, size.height + 5),
                  link: _layerLink,
                  showWhenUnlinked: false,
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: widget.dropdownStyle.elevation ?? 0,
                    color: widget.dropdownStyle.color,
                    shape: widget.dropdownStyle.shape,
                    child: SizeTransition(
                      axisAlignment: 1,
                      sizeFactor: _expandAnimation,
                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: widget.dropdownStyle.constraints ??
                            BoxConstraints(
                              maxHeight: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - topOffset - 15).isNegative
                                  ? 100
                                  : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - topOffset - 15,
                            ),
                        child: RawScrollbar(
                          thumbVisibility: true,
                          thumbColor: widget.dropdownStyle.scrollbarColor ?? Colors.grey,
                          controller: _scrollController,
                          child: ListView(
                            padding: widget.dropdownStyle.padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            controller: _scrollController,
                            children: widget.items.asMap().entries.map((item) {
                              return InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() => _currentIndex = item.key);
                                  widget.onChange(item.key);
                                  _toggleDropdown();
                                },
                                child: item.value,
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleDropdown({bool close = false}) async {
    if (_isOpen || close) {
      await _animationController.reverse();
      _overlayEntry.remove();
      setState(() {
        _isOpen = false;
      });
    } else {
      _overlayEntry = _createOverlayEntry();
      Overlay.of(context)?.insert(_overlayEntry);
      setState(() => _isOpen = true);
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }
}

/// DropdownItem is just a wrapper for each child in the dropdown list.\n
/// It holds the value of the item.
class DropdownItem<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final T? value;
  final Widget child;

  const DropdownItem({Key? key, this.value, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return child;
  }
}

class DropdownButtonStyle {
  final MainAxisAlignment? mainAxisAlignment;
  final ShapeBorder? shape;
  final double elevation;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final EdgeInsets? padding;
  final BoxConstraints? constraints;
  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final Color? primaryColor;

  const DropdownButtonStyle({
    this.mainAxisAlignment,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.primaryColor,
    this.constraints,
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.elevation = 0,
    this.padding,
    this.shape,
  });
}

class DropdownStyle {
  final double? elevation;
  final Color? color;
  final EdgeInsets? padding;
  final BoxConstraints? constraints;
  final Color? scrollbarColor;

  /// Add shape and border radius of the dropdown from here
  final ShapeBorder? shape;

  /// position of the top left of the dropdown relative to the top left of the button
  final Offset? offset;

  ///button width must be set for this to take effect
  final double? width;

  const DropdownStyle({
    this.constraints,
    this.offset,
    this.width,
    this.elevation,
    this.shape,
    this.color,
    this.padding,
    this.scrollbarColor,
  });
}
```

**Usage**

```
  CustomDropdown<int>(
      onChange: (int index) => print("index: $index"),
      dropdownButtonStyle: DropdownButtonStyle(
        height: 49,
        elevation: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        primaryColor: Colors.black87,
      ),
      dropdownStyle: DropdownStyle(
          elevation: 1,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.grey,
                width: 1,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7))),
      items: [
        'item 1',
        'item 2',
        'item 3',
        'item 4',
      ]
          .asMap()
          .entries
          .map(
            (item) => DropdownItem<int>(
              value: item.key + 1,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(item.value),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      child: Text(
        "Item 1",
      ),
    )
```