# DropdownButton itemMenu width

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

i am using dropdown button in my project. After clicking dropdownmenubutton it opens the list my  items are small (mon.tue,wed and so on) but the dropdown window is expanded till dropdown button. i want to decrease the width of the dropdownMenuitem width withouth changing the width of dropdwon button. I wrapped my dropdownbutton with container and provided the width but its also dreaccesing the width of dropdownbutton. Is there any way that i can only change the width of dropdwonmenu window and keeping isExpanded to true? Thanks in advance.

```
return Container(
 // width: 300.0,
  child: DropdownButton(
    isExpanded: true,
    value: name,
    items: listOfDropdownMenuItems,
    onChanged: onChanged,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
),
```

);

Answer (score 0):

try using package Dropdown Button 2  [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2)

After import, you can custom the width of dropdown

```
 dropdownStyleData: DropdownStyleData(
              width: 160,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
              elevation: 8,
              offset: const Offset(0, 8),
            ),
```

Comment: Đức Thành Lê thanks for your response.  I don't want to use any 3rd party packages which are not from flutter or flutter favourite , is there any other way to achive that??

Comment: Maybe, you can try to custom your own dropdown, using Overlay entry and stack. Basically, you will have a button , when tap it using overlay entry to mimic/show the dropdown ( which can be a container with custom width and child is a column)

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65685532/create-custom-dropdown-in-flutter-or-how-to-put-custom-dropdown-options-in-a-l